# Delete files in reverse order

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have to delete a lot of files daily (200k+) so I wrote a batch file that does the following call:

```
del *.* /S /F /Q
```

I don't care about any of the files that get generated, so `*.*` is fine. The files get deleted in alphabetical order, but they still take a couple minutes and I would like to speed this up. I that deleting the files in reverse alphabetical order would be nice because then I could execute two batch files in parallel. I know a python script would make it easy to do, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a batch file. If you have an easier way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Executing 2 scripts in parallel may even slow down this process, because HDD head will have to skip back and forth.

Comment: @David: Very good point.  With modern SSDs that's less of a problem, but still -- parallel execution is a tool for dealing with CPU-bound performance issues, not I/O-bound.  On the other hand, making a bunch of overlapping asynchronous requests can allow the drive controller to elevator sort them, which can significantly improve throughput on rotating media.  Or simply allow the head to stream writes, while a synchronous call that has to return to the user-mode program between requests might miss the deadline and require an entire extra rotation.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Never had luck with this yet. Always got worse results.

Comment: @DavidJashi: Elevator sorting is something traditionally found only in enterprise-level RAID controllers.  Thankfully SSDs are now commodity hardware and bypass all the issues relating to seek time.

Comment: you can use a multi task batch by Aacini to speed up your deleting process.

Comment: Your current method passes the whole lot off to the OS via CMD to delete and will be faster than running a script to delete files individually.  Running it as a scheduled task makes sense to me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devised a multi-thread solution that would make good use of the unused time gaps that may occur in differently timed devices. The idea is run the process at the maximum speed that allows the slowest device (ie: hard disk) when it is continuously used with no pauses. Of course, the result of this method will entirely depend on the computer hardware.

The Batch file below take in the first parameter the number of asynchronous threads that will be created. This way, the total number of files will be divided by this number and each resulting block of files will be processed by a different simultaneous thread.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Multi-thread file deleting program
if "%1" equ "Thread" goto ProcessBlock

rem Create the list of file names and count they
cd C:\TheFolder
set numFiles=0
(for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /S /A-D *.*') do (
   echo %%f
   set /A numFiles+=1
)) > "%temp%\fileNames.tmp"

rem Get number of threads and size of each block
set numThreads=%1
if not defined numThreads (
   set /A numThreads=1, blockSize=numFiles
) else (
   set /A blockSize=numFiles/numThreads
)

rem Create asynchronous threads to process block number 2 up to numThreads
if exist thread.* del thread.*
for /L %%t in (2,1,%numThreads%) do (
   echo %time% > thread.%%t
   start "" /B "%~F0" Thread %%t
)

rem Process block number 1
set count=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%temp%\fileNames.tmp") do (
   del "%%f"
   set /A count+=1
   if !count! equ %blockSize% goto endFirstBlock
)

:endFirstBlock

rem Wait for all asynchronous threads to end
if exist thread.* goto endFirstBlock

rem Delete the auxiliary file and terminate
del "%temp%\fileNames.tmp"
goto :EOF


rem Process blocks 2 and up (asynchronous thread)

:ProcessBlock 
set /A skip=(%2-1)*blockSize, count=0
for /F "usebackq skip=%skip% delims=" %%f in ("%temp%\fileNames.tmp") do (
   del "%%f"
   set /A count+=1
   if !count! equ %blockSize% goto endBlock
)
:endBlock
del thread.%2
exit
```

The above Batch file assume that file names have not exclamation marks. If this point is required, the appropriate setlocal/endlocal commands may be included, but this detail will slow down the process.

Ideally, you should do several timing tests with the same set of files varying the parameter starting at 1 and growing up until a value gives a timing greater than the previous one; however, I know this will be difficult in your case. However, you may vary the parameter each time you run the program and write down the timing. If the set of files is similar in each run, you will identify the best value for the parameter.

If you complete these timing tests, post the results please! I would like to review they.

Comment: This looks very promising. I have yet to try this. I consider this the best answer so far over scheduling tasks to delete files because I left out one piece of information - the location of the files deviate everyday as well as the size. I needed to delete 400k (2 gig) worth of data from a different location than yesterday. As a result, scheduling does not work. How exactly do I call this?